# How to respond whenever a new contact is added in android

Tags: android

I am new to android programming,i want to perform specific actions whenever a new contact is added to android device,In broadcast receivers,we have actions like `BOOT_COMPLETED`,similarly can we something for new contacts added,please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this question and answer, this may help you
[Phonebook Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426555/android-notify-when-phone-book-is-updatedcontent-observer).

This answer uses [ContentObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html)

Also you can use [SyncAdapters](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-2/) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6595892/1438915) answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is using the RAWContacts

There's no broadcast when a contact is added/changed. However, when you look up your contacts in the `RawContacts` table you have a `DIRTY` column which is `1` if the contact was changed since the last `sync`.

You can check

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html

for more information